# Display emails in mutt on ubuntu with postfix

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, mutt, postfix-mta

I am trying to configure my email server on aws instance running ubuntu. thought to start with postfix. I have configured postfix very well and I am able to send email from my aws instance to my gmail account but I have **some issues:**

- I have installed mutt to check the emails sent back to my email server from my gmail account or from any account when I start mutt it
  says **"/home/ubuntu/Mail is not a mailbox."** googling told this
  error is removed once postfix rcvs first email. But I have sent a
  reply( also separate email) to the ubuntu@mydmain.com( postfix user)
  and it does not bounce back( delivery report is okay in gmail
  account) that means email must've been rcvd by my postfix user.I am confused why mutt is not able to show email received by the user. Following is the **~/.muttrc:**

  > ```
  > set mbox_type=Maildir
  > set realname=ubuntu
  > set from =ubuntu@mydomain.com
  > set use_from = yes
  > set envelope_from = "yes"
  > set sendmail="/usr/bin/Postfix"
  > set spoolfile="~/Mail"
  > set folder="~/Mail"
  > set mask=".*"   
  > # set mask="!^\.[^.]"  
  > set record="+.Sent"
  > set mbox="~/Mail"
  > set postponed="+.Drafts"
  > ```

  **etc/postfix/main.cf:**

> ```
> smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu) 
> biff = no 
> readme_directory = no
>
>  smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt 
> smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key  
> smtpd_use_tls=yes 
> smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache  
> smtp_tls_session_cache_database= btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
>
> smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination 
> myhostname = mydomain.com 
> alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases 
> alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases 
> myorigin = mydomain.com 
> mydestination = mydomain.com, etc etc 
> localhost relayhost=  
> mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 
> mailbox_size_limit = 51200000  
> recipient_delimiter = +  
> inet_interfaces = all  
> inet_protocols = all 
> home_mailbox = ~/Mail  
> virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual 
> mailbox_command =  
> smtpd_sasl_local_domain =  
> smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
> smtpd_sasl_security_options = 
> noanonymous broken_sasl_auth_clients= yes 
> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination 
> smtp_tls_security_level = may 
> smtpd_tls_security_level = may 
> smtpd_tls_auth_only = no  
> smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes 
> smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem  
> smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1 
> smtpd_tls_received_header = yes  
> smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s 
>  tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
> ```

2. Second problem is that the email that I am sending are going with sender as Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Change `home_mailbox = ~/Mail` to `home_mailbox = /Mail` in `main.cf` only.

Change `set realname=ubuntu` to the name you want and change `set from =ubuntu@mydomain.com` to `set from="yourname <ubuntu@mydomain.com>"` in `~/.muttrc` to change your display name.

I'm assuming that you are sending your emails via mutt.